# how to convert categorical data to numerical data in for loop in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a categorical data framework and I want to convert it into numerical data, I have more than 50 columns so I want to run .repalce command in a loop.

```
replace_map =  {'w': 4, '+': 5, '.': 6, 'g': 7}
```

and I have written code which iterates over columns

```
for column in df1_replace.columns[1:76]:
# Select column contents by column name using [] operator
columnSeriesObj = df1_replace[column]
print('Colunm Name : ', column)
print('Column Contents : ', columnSeriesObj.values)
```

Comment: please add more details and try to add some refernce

Comment: yes. If you could provide sample data, what you have tried and expected output, it would be possible to provide a complete answer.

Comment: @nitin3685 how can I share an excel sheet here?

Comment: Please don't. Please copy only part of the  sample data into your question. No need of the 119 columns. just some sample ones with some columns which you want deleted. BTW also post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I upload the image kindly check

Comment: Please don't upload images. Text please. I cant use images in sample programs. :-) .. Which are the columns you want to drop? Are they columns like T and AD?

Comment: yes, I want to delete columns like t and AD, B, C, D, E, I want to delete all duplicates columns. make columns size small for feature selections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could do it using [`dropna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and [`drop_duplicated()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)
I have used my own sample data with one column with no values.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = StringIO('''2001,1,,a,a
        2001,2,,b,b
        2001,3,,c,c
        2005,1,,a,a
        2005,1,,c,c''')
df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None )
print(df)
```

`df` will look like this

```
      0  1   2  3  4
0  2001  1 NaN  a  a
1  2001  2 NaN  b  b
2  2001  3 NaN  c  c
3  2005  1 NaN  a  a
4  2005  1 NaN  c  c
```

Then drop all columns (`how='all'`) where all values are `na(NaN)`

```
df_new = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

Take a transpose of the dataframe, the duplicate columns will become duplicate rows. Then use `drop_duplicates` on it to drop duplicate rows. Transpose it back to get your original data, without empty columns and duplicate columns.

```
df_new = df_new.T.drop_duplicates().T
df_new.columns = range(len(df_new.columns))
print(df_new)
```

Comment: Sir, there are no null values in my dataset, duplicates columns are there, I want to delete duplicate columns.

Comment: Please check now. I have added how to remove empty columns and duplicate columns. I showed how to remove empty columns as well since your data sample had completely empty columns.

Comment: Thanks, how can i reindex my new data frame after removing duplicates columns e.g  after removing duplicates columns indexes are 0, 1,15,34,35, and i want in 0,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Check now. BTW, please edit your question to add the sample data in text format and the new requirements :-). It will help other people who are looking to do similar things. Also if the answer is acceptable to you, don't forget to vote and accept the answer

Comment: can you give me your email address so that I can discuss my real problem with you i am new in DataScience.

Comment: Contact detail are part of my profile. Please note, it is considered good etiquette to post completely edited questions and accept and close answers on SO.